# Can't find the proper settings to import Europe map using osm2pgsql?

Tags: openstreetmap, import, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to deploy a map server, i used http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/.

My server setup is: Xeon E3-1230v2 Quad-qore, 16GB RAM DDR3, 2x2TB HDD in Software RAID-1 array, running Ubunutu Server 14.04

I use putty to SSH in to it, i don't know how to see why it breaks the import process but i assume the reason is the memory settings. I have dynamic ip at home, so after i set it to import i might lose connection to the server, and when i relog i can't see the import process, but i know it is importing as i check the server load, but it brakes.

Is there a command to show importing process?

I have 7GB of swap memory.

The latest settings i used are: 
osm2pgsql --slim  -C 12000 --number-processes 2 europe-latest.osm.pbf

shared_buffers 1024MB

maintenance_work_mem = 1024MB

checkpoint_segments = 100

autovacuum = off (import only setting!)

What should i do?

I would ultimately need the import Europe and North America, also i want to deploy Nominatim 2, for the both regions.

Can my server handle it?

If not what setup am i looking at?

Please be more detailed in your suggestions as i'm not prolific user of Linux.

Comment: To address your problem of dynamic IPs and the ssh connection not staying open you can use the "screen" command to create a virtual screen. See "man screen" command, or http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html